# Validation Filters for specific controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, controller, asp.net-web-api

In a Web API or ASP.NET MVC application I can add a Global validation filter by doing -

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ModelValidationFilterAttribute());
```

and

```
public class ModelValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    } 
}
```

But I want to have many validations filters that apply to controllers of my choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are attributes that can be applied to your controllers or specific methods/actions in your controllers.

To use your filter on a case-by-case basis, you can do either of the following:

```
[MyFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //Filter will be applied to all methods in this controller
}
```

Or:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [MyFilter]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
         //Filter will be applied to this specific action method
    }
}
```

[This tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) describes filters in detail and provides examples of both scenarios.